# siunitx—how do I get exponents with uncertainties?

Tags: siunitx

I am typesetting a lab report with indirectly-measured values of a diffraction grating's grating spacing; these values are on the orders of micrometres, which are more easily expressed in scientific notation; otherwise, I'd have too many leading zeroes.

However, when I type something like `\SI{1.80812E-6(0.0044)}{\m}`, I receive a compilation error:

```
Package siunitx Error: Invalid exponent in numerical input(siunitx) '1.80812E-6(0.0044)'. ...as found to be \SI{1.80812E-6(0.0044)}{\m}.
```

Apparently `pdflatex` thinks the uncertainty is for the exponent, as detailed in the log file:

```
The exponent part of a number cannot contain an uncertainty or complex part: the input given appears to contain one of these in the exponent.
```

How may I remedy this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \SI{1.80812(440)E-6}{\m}

    \SI[separate-uncertainty]{1.80812(440)E-6}{\m}
\end{document}
```

[image]